# How to place div / text inside a highchart

Tags: backbone.js, highcharts

I am using a highchart.. depending on the selection people make on the chart, i would like to display different text inside the graph. How can i achieve this?

[image]

```
handleRefresh : function(ChartModel) {
        var chartOptions = new ChartTheme();
.......
.......
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions.options);
}

updateColumnSelection : function(index){
  var data = this.model.getData(index);
  _.each(data.messages, function(msg) {
    //display message
    //pool: yes
    var dataPlacement = $("#messages");
dataPlacement .html('');
    dataPlacement.append(msg);

 }
}
```

Best way to do is, I don't know if possible, but i would love to have a div (place holder) inside the graph and just update it with every selection.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Maybe show an example? Generally, you're probably going to need a js listener and to either dynamically create content or show/hide stuff.

Comment: no code no accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look the reference, [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Element) you can see how to add new elements to the chart. Create the element with an `id`, so that you can get it using `jQuery`.
Then you can use the `selection` event to update the number.

```
{
    chart: {
        renderTo: #element,
        events: {
            selection: function() {
                // @todo Update message
            }
        }
    }
}
```